# Python: Create an element inside an element

Tags: python, list, indexing

So for a school project I have to create some playing field and afterwards it has to be checked.

My thought was to add a grid in python, just a simple list

```
grid = ([[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
         [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
         [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
         [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
         [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
         [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']])
```

As you can see it's 6 elements, each containing 6 spaces.
the grid.insert only works for adding elements but not for these 'element elements'.

the idea is that when,

```
if x == 25 and y == 25:
```

then grid becomes:

```
([['1',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']])
```

Is this even possible in python? Or should I look for a different way of solving this?

I hope this is enough information, else I will glady supply you with more!

Comment: What's the significance of 25? Do you mean when `x == 5 and y == 5`?

Comment: Why do you change the item [0][0] when x and y are 25?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
There are many other postings showing how to initialize a 2-D list such as this.  Where are you stuck with those?

Comment: @DyZ. It's a python-turtle project. We have to create a nonogram in turtle and when a square is clicked, it turns black. the squares are 25x25, i was just using x =25 as an example. but to make it better:

when x and y both are 0
then [0][0] has to turn into 1... at least thats what I thought was easy..

Comment: OK, but that still doesn't explain why x=25, y=25 maps to row 0, col 0 of a 6x6 grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you could create the array using a for loop nested inside such as

```
grid = [(["*",]*6)for i in range(6)]
```

Then to append just do

```
grid[0][0] = 1
```

Maybe another idea for printing it out is

```
rowFormat=("{:<5}")*6
for i in range(len(grid)):
   print(rowFormat.format(*grid[i]))
```

something like that. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you know the point you're trying to change you can just do it by directly referencing the point e.g.

```
grid[0][1] = 1
```

where the first brackets is which list and then the second brackets is the index within that list
Or if you're trying to check the spaces for a value you can use the referencing in a similar way

```
if grid[0][1] == "1":
    Do Stuff
```

Otherwise I'm not sure what you're asking for...

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I meant! I'm sorry for the way I put it to words, I'm kind of new to programming and my teacher at school thinks everybody is a Python-coding god.

thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To access an element of a list, you can use `my_list[i]`, where `i` is the position of the element you want to access. To access an element within an element of a list, you can use `my_list[i][j]`, where `i` is the position of your highest level element and `j` is the position of the element within the element. Note that the first position of a list is `0` and not `1`. You can then change this element to whatever you want it to contain by setting it equal to something.